# Delphi 4 Unable to open a .dpr file

Tags: delphi

How are you?

I was trying to open an .dpr file from my IDE , it closes all the open .pas files ,but does not open .dpr file.I tried 1) file/open project 2) cntr+F11 3)clicking open on the file.
None of them work.Kindly help me in figuring out how to run an .dpr file.

Thanks and Regards
Vas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The .dpr doesn't show by default when you open a project.  In the menu, go to Project|View Source.

Comment: Thank you very much Bruce.It was working!

on another note:-
But it always opens "Project 1.dpr".
Where as my project is name "ABCtest"
So I am saving "Project 1.dpr" it as "ABCtest.dpr"


-Regards
Vas

Comment: Hi Vas. If you go to View|Project Manager, do you have more than one project open? Your existing project (ABCTest) and a new one, which would default to "Project1"?

Comment: Hi Bruce!I did as per above and it was working. But an different note.. When I add files to a project in the project builder, error pops up "THTMLViewr not found. Ignore the error and continue? NOTE: This may cause...."on “cancel” the error is "error creating THTML .Class not found”.

Comment: Also I have installed Thtml in .C:/Program Files/PBear/ HTMLComponents/ Thtml/Package”  and mapped it in “Projects/Options/Directories and Conditionals/Search Path/” and  Tools/environmental options/Library/Library Path/ and mapped it in  “$(DELPHI)\Lib;$(DELPHI)\Bin;$(DELPHI)\Imports;$(DELPHI) \Lib; $(DELPHI)\  Bin;$(DELPHI)\ Imports;C:\Program Files\ PBear\ HTML Components\Package “

Comment: Sounds like Delphi can't find the source files.  Are they in the that Package directory?  If not, include the source directory in your library path.  If this doesn't help, take a step back.  Start a new project and try to add the HTML viewer.  If you don't have any luck, ask a new question.  Someone who is using these components might have had the same problem.

Comment: I overlooked the library mapping path which was not correct.So When I added "C:/Program Files/PBear/ HTMLComponents/ Thtml/Package" to "Tools/environmental options/Library/Library Path/ " it was working.Thanks Bruce